# Passing A File Created Using Powershell To Jenkinsfile

Tags: powershell, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I created a file using Powershell within Jenkinsfile:

```
pwsh(returnStdout: true, script: '. "' + env.WORKSPACE + '/folder/functions.ps1"' + '''

  $serversList = (Get-servers).keys | out-file - FilePath .\\serversList.txt

'''
```

I am unable to find this file when looking for it using Groovy. I wish to pass this file and use it in my jenkinsfile.

I was unable to find any answer for this use case online.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should first ensure that the file was actually created by logging into the Jenkins host machine and looking there manually. If the file is indeed there, note its location and use `dir` to specify the directory first. Then use `readFile` to read the contents of the file:

```
dir("path\\to\\serversList.txt"){
    def data = readFile(file: 'serversList.txt')
}
```